# CSS Triangle using :after psuedo element displaying as a rectangle instead in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, geometry, pseudo-element

I have a triangle that is :after each table element in a form (don't talk to me about the markup.. I only have access to the CSS >.>) and in IE9/IE10/Chrome/FF it is working fine. However, when I check it in IE8, instead of a triangle I get a solid rectangle instead.

Here is the css:

```
.wSectionTableCSS:after {
content: "";
bottom: -38px;
left: 17px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 25px 0 0 20px;
border-color: rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.13) transparent;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
    margin: 0 0 0 -20px !important;
    position: relative;
overflow: visible;
display: inherit;}
```

[How it currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTLwX.png)

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIqNm.png)

Do you have any idea what might be effecting the triangle shape (and transparency while we're at it)?

Comment: `border-color` with `rgba` is not supported in IE8. this might help, but no promises => http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: I checked that out, but I'm  not sure how to apply that transparency filter to a border color (and not a background).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there is a DocType declared, or IE8 won't understand the :after pseudo selector.

If you can live without the rgba alpha, here are some examples of CSS triangles that work in IE8: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Comment: It looks like that requires additional layers - I don't have access to editing the html, unfortunately.